# Downloading MODIS data using Python with help of shapefiles

Tags: python, shapefile, modis, download

I want to download MODIS data at 250m (2 bands) and 500m (5 bands) for arond 2700 regions. I have the shapefiles for each of the region.

How can I download the raw MODIS data (surface reflectance) using Python (*no GUI GIS software to be involved*) using shapefiles (Esri format)?

I have also calculated the convex hull for each shapefile region, in case that is needed.

The code below uses latitude and longitude to cover the region - but this is not neat. It can miss tiles. besides this doesn't use the shapefiles.

```py
import ee
import time
import sys
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import itertools
import os
import urllib

ee.Initialize()

def export_oneimage(img,folder,name,region,scale,crs):
  task = ee.batch.Export.image(img, name, {
      'driveFolder':folder,
      'driveFileNamePrefix':name,
      'region': region,
      'scale':scale,
      'crs':crs
  })
  task.start()
  while task.status()['state'] == 'RUNNING':
    print 'Running...'
    # Perhaps task.cancel() at some point.
    time.sleep(10)
  print 'Done.', task.status()




locations = pd.read_csv('locations.csv')


# Transforms an Image Collection with 1 band per Image into a single Image with items as bands
# Author: Jamie Vleeshouwer

def appendBand(current, previous):
    # Rename the band
    previous=ee.Image(previous)
    current = current.select([0,1,2,3,4,5,6])
    # Append it to the result (Note: only return current item on first element/iteration)
    accum = ee.Algorithms.If(ee.Algorithms.IsEqual(previous,None), current, previous.addBands(ee.Image(current)))
    # Return the accumulation
    return accum

imgcoll = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/MOD09A1') \
    .filterBounds(ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-106.5, 50,-64, 23))
img=imgcoll.iterate(appendBand)

for loc1, loc2, lat, lon in locations.values:
    fname = '{}_{}'.format(int(loc1), int(loc2))

    offset = 0.11
    scale  = 500
    crs='EPSG:4326'

    region = str([
        [lat - offset, lon + offset],
        [lat + offset, lon + offset],
        [lat + offset, lon - offset],
        [lat - offset, lon - offset]])

    while True:
        try:
            export_oneimage(img,'Data',fname,region,scale,crs)
        except:
            print 'retry'
            time.sleep(10)
            continue
        break
```

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: I know how to do it using QGIS - but that is useful only when number of regions is like 10-20. For 2700 manual method is useless. Also, while downloading the data, each polygon may cover more than one tile, so how to mosaic them using Python is also part of the question. I have come across PyModis, but an example would help.

Comment: Check the [AppEEARS API](https://lpdaacsvc.cr.usgs.gov/appeears/api). They have the product you want and give you the option to filter it by a geographical region. You can integrate it with Python using `requests` or `urllib`.

Comment: @MarceloVilla This API is not very useful, AppEEARS doesn't have raw satellite data but some highly processed/compressed version of it - not useful.

Comment: For some reason, GEE doesn't allow downloading MODIS surface reflectance data unless you have a paid Google Cloud bucket subscription. I ended up downloading the data manually.